# Просмотр данных базы данных в .mdf

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Есть проект на С#(Скачал). Все работает после запуска через VS.Не могу просмотреть содержимое файла(.mdf). Пробовал все варианты (SSMS, устанавливал левые проги). В SQL Server пишет, что нет редактора. Может что-то неправильно делаю?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в ssms подключитесь к серверу, ткните там в него в дереве и найдите attach database, выберите ваш файл. или LocalDB поставить.